# How to pack JRE/JDK into .jar

Tags: java, linux, windows, jar, zip

I'm trying to create application in Java. I found some articles how to pack some stuff into one .jar file, but I need other funcionality.

I want to pack JRE/JDK into .jar and use it to run this .jar file.
Is it possible?

Comment: No, basically. If you start with a jar file, what are you expecting to *open* the jar file to extract the JRE? There *are* tools available to bundle Java packages into a single executable, but I've always found them to cause hard-to-diagnose problems. IMO it's better to provide a regular Windows installer which extracts a private copy of the JRE, along with your app code.

Comment: Ok so I need to install java first to run it? I can't run .jar with JRE that I have packed inside? Thanks Jon

Comment: No, because something's got to know what to do with the jar file, right? That "something" is Java... so you have a bootstrapping problem. It's like trying to enter a building where the only key is already inside the building..

Comment: Yes, I understand it. I thought just about some kind of workaround :) Thanks